Showing that a ball is a convex set
So in geometry class we saw that a ball is convex, we didn't really prove it we just "saw it" intuitively. I thought maybe I could prove it using just the properties of the distance function, aka, the three axioms of a metric. So what I want to prove is that if two points $p$, $q$ have a distance from a third point $x$ lesser than a positive radius $r$, then every point "between" $p$ and $q$ also has a distance from $x$ lesser than $r$. We defined a point as being between two points if the triangle inequality is an equality. In symbols, I want to show that for every metric space $(X, d)$ (although in theory I should only need to show it for $\mathbb{R}^3$ with euclidean metric):
$(\forall r > 0)(\forall x, p, q, k \in X)[(d(x, p) < r)  \land (d(x, q) < r) \land (d(p, q) = d(p, k) + d(k, q))] \implies d(x, k) < r$
So far what I've done is suppose $r, x, p, q, k$ arbitrary from an arbitraty metric space $(X, d)$, then suppose $d(x, p) < r  \land d(x, q) < r \land d(p, q) = d(p, k) + d(k, q)$. By triangle inequality we have $d(x, p) + d(p, k) \geq d(x, k)$ and also $d(x, q) + d(q, k) \geq d(x, k)$, combining both we get $d(x, p) + d(p, k) + d(x, q) + d(q, k) \geq 2d(x, k)$ and by hypothesis we have $2r + d(p, q) \geq 2d(x, k)$ and then by triangle inequality we get: $2r + d(p, x) + d(x, q) \geq 2d(x, k)$ which by hypothsis means $4r \geq 2d(x, k)$ which means $d(x, k) \leq 2r$.
I was really hoping manipulating the inequalities would end up with $d(x, k) < r$, but I can't find a way to get to this with only triangle inequality and the two other axioms. So then anoter thing I thought of doing was looking at the set $A = \{d(x, k)\}$ for fixed $r, x, p, q$. Basically the sex of all distances a point $k$ between $p$ and $q$ can have with respect to $x$. Because of what we showed before, this set is bounded and in fact $2r$ is an upper bound. Also the set is not empty since $d(x, q)$ belongs to it (point $q$ is between $p$ and $q$). So then $\sup A$ exists. I was hoping maybe by assuming $r \leq \sup A \leq 2r$ I could find another number lesser than $\sup A$ that is also an upper bound, therefore contradicting the assumption that $\sup A \geq r$ and showing that $d(x, k) < r$.
Keep in mind, I have not taken a topology class, all I know about metric spaces are the 3 axioms and the definition of convex and a point being between two others, can I realistically prove this with this approach? If so, please give me hints, if on the other hand you think I am missing crucial information about metric spaces that is required for the proof (so important theorem or concept), please tell which things I should read about. Sorry if this question is too obvious, but I am afraid to Google it because I don't want to get spoiled, I would really like to prove this so that I can show my work in class. Thanks for your time.

In a normed space it follows because of the triangle inequality.

@copper.hat Thanks! I have never read about normed spaces before, but reading the definition is like a vector space where every vector has a "lenght", So what I would have to prove is that if two vectors are contained in the sphere, that is $||p|| < r$ and $||q|| < r$ then every vector between them $k$ also has $||k|| < r$. And here $k$ would be between $p$ and $q$ if $||p-q|| = ||p-k|| + ||k-q||$, right?

A metric space doesn't have enough structure to talk about convexity, for example, the rationals with absolute value as metric cannot be convex because of the 'holes'. In a normed space over the real/complex numbers, it is straightforward, using properties of the norm to show that the ball $B(p,r)$ is convex: if $x,y \in B(p,r)$ and $t \in [0,1]$ then $|tx+(1-t)y -p | \le t |x-p| + (1-t)|y-p| <r $.

@copper.hat I see, there's still one thing I don't understand, I get that for $t \in [0, 1]$ the vector $k = tx + (1-t)y$ is supposed to represent a vector that is "between" $x$ and $y$, and I was able to verify that indeed this vector has the property that $||x - y|| = ||x - k|| + ||k - y||$, however I don't know how to prove that for every vector $k$ for which it holds $||x - y|| = ||x - k|| + ||k - y||$, then there is some $t \in [0, 1]$ such that $k =  tx + (1-t)y$, would you give me any hints as to how I should choose $t$ for a specific $k$?

I'm not sure what you are trying to prove, but equality does not hold in general for a norm. I used the triangle inequality above, which holds for all norms.

What I'm trying to prove is that, in a normed vector space, given two vectors $x$ and $y$, then for every vector $k$ between $x$ and $y$, that is for every vector $k$ for which this is true: $||x−y||=||x−k||+||k−y||$ then there exists $t \in [0, 1]$ such that $k = tx+(1−t)y$ In other words, I want to prove that the notion of "a vector between two vectors" that you provided and the one I was given in class are the same.

It is not true in general in normed spaces, take the metric $|x|+|y|$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $x=(1,0), y=(0,1), k=(1,1)$ satisfies the equation but clearly $k$ does not lie on the segment $[x,y]$. I would focus on your specific problem first and then generalise.

@copper.hat I see so it's not really true for all normed spaces, but would it be true for $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual norm?

Yes. If $k$ lies on the line through $x,y$ then show that $t \in [0,1]$, otherwise consider the projection of $k$ onto the line (say $k'$) and use Pythagoras to express the distances from $x,y$ to $k$ to show that $t \in [0,1]$ and $k=k'$.

Unfortunately, it's not true that a ball in a metric space is always a convex set (with respect to a linear structure on that metric space). For example, this property fails in $\Bbb R^2$ under the Paris metric: the set of all points at distance less than $2$ from $(1,0)$ is the union of the open ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin and the (open) segment from $(0,0)$ to $(3,0)$.
So one has to use something about the specific metric that generates a ball in $\Bbb R^d$. If it helps, one can restrict to the plane through the origin and the two points $p$ and $q$, so it suffices to show that an open disc in the plane is convex.

The question seems to be about a concept of convexity that depends only on the metric: ‘We defined a point as being between two points if the triangle inequality is an equality.’

Thanks! I'm glad I asked, otherwise I would have been stuck trying to prove something that isn't true. I do remember reading that open balls are always convex, but I guess they must use a definition of convex different from the one we saw in class, the one in class must have been pretty specific to Euclidean Geometry
